# Why can the equation Ax = b not be solved for every b

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

> Let $A$ be a $3 \times 2$ matrix . Explain why the equation $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$ cannot be solved for every $\vec{b}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. What about a $4 \times 3$ matrix?

I'm not sure how to answer this.. I know that a $3 \times 2$ matrix only has 2 pivot columns and could therefore only have 2 pivot positions maybe? I also know that the third row would have to be like maybe infinitely solutions or? I'm not really sure how to explain it

Comment: **Hint:** Would you be able to solve it if $A$ were in row-echelon (or reduced row-echelon) form?

Comment: well then I would have $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ right @Omnomnomnom ?

Comment: And wouldn't that mean that I have **infinitely many solutions** ?

Comment: What if the last equation was $0=1$?

Comment: Then that would mean no solution!

Comment: So a 3x2 cannot be solved because there could be a possibility of no solution ?

Comment: Hint: The vector $x$ lives in $\mathbb{R}^2$, thus the map $A:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ is mapping the plane into 3D space, and it is a linear map. What might the image of $\mathbb{R}^2$ look like in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: oh wait its like saying the domain is the dimensions in 2d space and then its saying its co domain is in 3d space so everything wouldnt map right right?

Comment: Essentially yes, what happens is that the image of $A$ (viewed as a map) is at most a plane (or it might only be a line or even just a point in the most degenerate case). The reason has to do with the concept of *rank* of a matrix. A $3\times 2$ matrix cannot have rank$>2$, hence the image cannot be all of $\mathbb{R}^3$. (Thus there exists some $b$ such that $Ax=b$ has no solution).

Comment: I'm assuming the same rules apply in a 4x3 matrix? thank a matrix rank cannot be > 3?

Comment: You're right about the rank. I also want to point out that the reason that the rank is always less than or equal to the dimension of the domain is that the image of a linear transformation (i.e. the column space of the matrix) is spanned by the images of the basis vectors of the domain. (So if your domain is $\mathbb R^2$, as for a $3\times 2$ matrix and you look at the standard basis $e_1,e_2$, then the column space of $A$ will be spanned by $Ae_1, Ae_2$, so it can have dimension at most $2$.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$ deined by $$T(X)=AX.$$ Now existence of solution for $AX=b$ means that $b\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$ has preimage under $T$ and which is not possible for every vector of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ as $T$ can't onto. Same is true for the matrix mention by you.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is a matrix and $b$ a vector. what   means the equation $Ax=b$
has solutions or not?

possesses solutions means that the vector $b$ is in the sub space
spanned by the column vectors of $A$. If $B$ is the matrix
obtained by concatenating $A$ and $b$, then this is equivalent to
$rank (A) = rank (B)$; by negation so that $Ax = b$ admits no
solution iff  $b$ is not in the space generated by the columns of
$A$ ie $rank (B) = rank (A) +1$

In the case of a non-square matrix there is an infinity of $b$ in
the space that satisfies $rank (A) = rank (B)+ 1$ and also an
infinity of $b$ that satisfies $rank (A) = rank ( B)$.